# What is this ground-hugging dense flowering plant?

Tags: identification, ground-cover

What is this ground-hugging dense flowering plant?

What appears as a sort of stair in the photo is actually a concrete container for this plant (which is invisible, entirely covered by the plant), and the plant seems to have escaped the container, and continues to spread and progress slowly...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Leaves indicate either Aubretia or Arabis...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flower structure (4 petals, 6 stamens with 2 shorter than the others) indicates to me that this is a member of the family Brassicaceae. I suspect an Arabis of some kind, maybe [Arabis caucasica](http://www.phengels.fr/macro11-93.html).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the pictures I vote for Veronica spp. A Speedwell ground cover. [image: Veronica or Speedwell]